# Error a abrir un proyecto en Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms

Estaba probando mi proyecto (compilandolo), y se me apago la compu. Cuando volvi a iniciar Visual Studio me sale el siguiente mensaje: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y reinicio visual studio y me sigue mostrando el mismo mensaje.. 
Ocupo ayuda por favor!!

Comment: prueba a eliminar el archivo que te dice `ActivytyLog.xml` o a cambiarlo de directorio.

Comment: Hola Hector, eso dañaría el proyecto?

Comment: no tiene por que, primero mira si te deja ejecutar Visual, si es así, no creo que te cueste mucho reconstruir ese fichero, de todas maneras puedes hacer una copia del proyecto antes de nada, por si las moscas.

Comment: Intente borrar el  `ActivytyLog.xml` pero cuando abro el proyecto, se vuelve a hacer solo el archivo

Comment: eliminalo de la carpeta debug, creo que ahí está tu problema que lo estas compilando y estás duplicando el archivo

Comment: Es que ni siquiera me abre el proyecto en visual... En cual carpeta debug? En la del proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Proba eliminando el:

```
c:\Users\LuisDuarte\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_7e9ccc52\ComponentModelCache
```

o bien el archivo `AnctivityLog.xml`

No va a dañar tu proyecto.

Comment: No encuentro el archivo ComponentModelCache